# Jackson recursion depth - infinite recursion using Maps (not POJOs)

Tags: json, recursion, jackson

I'de like to serialize an immutable Map, however, the Map has cyclical references (e.g. map of maps of maps). I can't use any of the POJO annotations (backrefs, Ignore, etc.) as its a dynamic model. I just want to specify the max depth to traverse down the map tree (graph).

Anyone know the easiest way to control the depth of the serializer in either configuration, or perhaps how to override the recursive traversal method in jackson?

Comment: you will have to write custom serializer